pass the search item into url
I am trying to learn react by practising a simple problem.
I followed the below youtube tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AsvybgZTryo&list=PLKhlp2qtUcSZiWKJTi5-5r6IRdHhxP9ZU&index=17
but when I search for an item the item is not passing properly in the  api call
https://dummyjson.com/users/search?q=${searchTerm}
can you let me know what is the issue, providing the codse snippet and stackblitz below
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUsers = () => {
      if (searchTerm.trim() === '') {
        setSuggestions([]);
        return;
      }
      fetch('https://dummyjson.com/users/search?q=${searchTerm}')
        .then((res) => {
          res.json();
        })
        .then((data) => setSuggestions(data))
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log('error', err);
        });
    };
    fetchUsers();
  }, [searchTerm]);


Don't you need template literals aka ticks? ``

Indeed. To clarify, try const number = 68; console.log('${number}'); vs const number = 68; console.log(\${number}`);; the difference being'_vs_``.

Problem is you are using ' instead of `
So, your code should be
fetch(`https://dummyjson.com/users/search?q=${searchTerm}`)
        .then((res) => {
          res.json();
        })
        .then((data) => setSuggestions(data))
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log('error', err);
        });

Ref: Back-tick vs single quote in js

Back-tick (`) instead of Single quote (')
Copy the whole code here
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUsers = () => {
      if (searchTerm.trim() === '') {
        setSuggestions([]);
        return;
      }
      fetch(`https://dummyjson.com/users/search?q=${searchTerm}`)
        .then((res) => {
          res.json();
        })
        .then((data) => setSuggestions(data))
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log('error', err);
        });
    };
    fetchUsers();
  }, [searchTerm]);

In JavaScript, backticks (`) are used to create template literals
reference:
https://www.dhiwise.com/post/unlock-the-power-of-js-backtick-template-literals-for-react
